# Does the scope of this site extend to virtual networking?

Tags: discussion

For example vDS or Nexus 1000v.

[Example here.](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191/extending-mpls-in-to-vswitches)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely. All OSI layers! :*)

Comment: All OSI layers, please. There is tons of networking gear that operates on layer 7.

Comment: ...good point. I edited my answer.

Comment: And for that matter layers 0 & 8 (& 9...)

Comment: I think L9 is reserved for the politics SE site currently in proposal on Area 51

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a reason to exclude the [CSR1000V](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/cloud-services-router-1000v-series/qa_c67-710278.html) ; it's intended to be used in real, production networks.

I don't like the referenced question though, because it's too broad.  It doesn't even limit scope to only vDS or the 1000v.